# Add VBA Project to Visio Document by Using Code

Tags: vba, visio

I've been asked to create a macro to update a few hundred or so Visio drawings, and keep them updated.

The update involves putting all objects of a certain type on their own layer - simple.

Now, this is easy enough to do, but when a user adds a new object some time in the future it will likely be on a default layer. So I had hoped to be able to include a VBA macro which is triggered by the Save event to re-assign objects to their layers.
The problem here is that I'd need to include this macro in every document since Visio doesn't have an application level VBA project.

Is there any way to introduce a VBA project to ALL Visio documents using code (VBA or otherwise)?? Or is there an alternative I might not have considered? Unfortunately an Add-in is not really an option due to available resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options here:

1. Force every user to allow programmatic access to the VBA project for their documents, and use VBA automation to add code.  This works nicely when you have programmatic access, but this can be difficult to assure.
2. If you're not using Visio 2013, you can actually save a document as VDX (xml) and replace the data for the VBA project with your own (you'd save out a document as VDX manually, and copy out the chunk of data for the VBA project).  As I said, this wouldn't work with Visio 2013 since they seem to have eliminated the VDX format.  You probably can get away with something similar with the VSDX XML format for 2013.
3. You can 'migrate' everyone's documents to a new VST file you provide.  This would just involve copying and pasting all the content from a document into the new document that has your code in it.  You have to be careful though to make sure all the document- and page-level data comes along, too (meaning DocumentSheet and PageSheet and any Document XML properties that may be important, and attributes like Author, Description, etc...)

Item 1 is the easiest, aside from the pain getting programmatic access to VBA Projects, unless you can have people send you documents to migrate.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Getting access to all the files isn't a problem, we're using a file store system. Do you have any more information about getting programmatic access to the VBA project? I haven't been able to find anything useful.

I think I've figured out your second Suggestion, and that looks plausible, although I would run into problems if there was an existing VBA Project in any of the files - But I don't think that's the case.

Option 3 is clever! I never thought about that, but you're right, few other things to think about there.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: It's pretty easy to set up programmatic VBA access on your machine...just go to the Visio trust center (Tools->Macros->Security in Visio<=2007, File->Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings and toggle on 'Trust access to the VBA project object model'

Comment: Oh, that much I understand. My question is how do I copy VBA code into other documents? Your second and third option address this, but it would be nice if I could copy the VBA project from one file to another using VBA. But it seems that the VBA project object is read only from within VBA itself...

Comment: For #3 you wouldn't have to copy any VBA code, but if you went with #1 then you just have to write some not-too-complicated code to do it. http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/programmatically-create-a-module-and-write-to-a-it/  and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640258/Deconstruction-of-a-VBA-Code-Module  seem to be pretty good primers